# Next.js getServerSideProps is calling fetch on the client side

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

For a page using `getServerSideProps`, if I direct go to that page, the page will be rendered at server side and no `fetch` is observed in the browser.

However, if I use `<Link>` from other pages that navigate to this page, I observe `fetch` behavior in my browser with the URL like this `http://url/_next/data/BUILD-ID/search.json?q=abc`. This will return the props in a json format.

Therefore, is this the intended behavior of SSR? Can I always ask the server to return the HTML instead of the props json?

Comment: "is this the intended behavior of SSR? " yes it is intended behaviour of `getServerSideProps`. The method is always executed "server side". If you want some logic to run on a client you could use old [`getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I want the exact opposite, I want it always returns the HTML on the client side, meaning no `fetch` happens in the browser.

Comment: If you want full page reload just use normal `<a>`. But the real question is why would you need it? It will send full html on the first hit and send props only on in-app navigation which is desired behaviour in most of the cases.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization

Comment: @YuryTarabanko what about the scenario where i don't want the user to be able to access api (e.g. api is a premium feature)? would using <a> instead of <Link> everywhere successfully force HTML generation at all times?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is an intended behavior:

Nextjs renders the page on the server side and then uses client rendering all the time.

A workaround I found is to use `<a href="link"></a>` instead of `<Link></Link>` because a hrefs do not trigger client rendering as Link does.